# Открыть активное приложение из notificationBuilder

Tags: java, android

Как я могу открывать активное но свернутое приложение из NotificationCompat.Builder(context) какой интент ему надо передавать или как то по другому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
    .setAutoCancel(false)
    .setTicker(getString(R.string.app_full_name))
    .setContentText(getString(R.string.app_full_name))
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

Notification statusNotification = nb.build();
manager.notify(id, statusNotification);
```

---

**upd:** 
Тогда нужно добавить флаг, попробуйте так:

```
 intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

или так:

```
 intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: Она открывает новое активити, а мне нужно открывать свернутое приложение, к примеру я открыл приложение и свернул его,  потом может через некоротое время вывел notification по нажатию которого должно открываться это свернутое приложение а не заново открывать.

Comment: @JTan, Обновил ответ.